# How can i click on a QGroupBox's CheckBox programatically

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pytest

I want to click on the [builtin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgroupbox.html#checkable-prop) (enabling) checkbox of a QGroupBox programmatically during testing with pytest-qt.

But i can't find out how to access the underlying checkbox widget of the groupbox via an attribute or similar methods.

Basically i could just use the `.setChecked(True)` method in my test but this would not be a "real" mouse click.

Is there a to access the checkbox widget of the groupbox directly?

Comment: Hi! Is that what you are looking for? `void setChecked(bool checked)` passing the argument true will check the checkbox, as if a user had clicked on it.

Comment: If you carefully read my question, it's not

Comment: Sorry, just saw I wrote setEnabled instead of setChecked

Answer (score 1):

Click action involves pressButton and releaseButton mouse events. So we can emulate click action by sending two sequential events to the destination widget.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , m_groupBox(new QGroupBox)
{
    m_groupBox->setCheckable(true);

    QPushButton* generateClickButton = new QPushButton("generate click");

    connect(generateClickButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]
    {
        clickAt(m_groupBox, Qt::LeftButton);
    });

    setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    layout()->addWidget(m_groupBox);
    layout()->addWidget(generateClickButton);

    resize(100, 100);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{}

void Widget::clickAt(QWidget* receiver, Qt::MouseButton button)
{
    if (receiver)
    {
        QMouseEvent pressEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, receiver->pos(), button, 0, 0);
        QMouseEvent releaseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, receiver->pos(), button, 0, 0);

        QApplication::sendEvent(receiver, &pressEvent);
        QApplication::sendEvent(receiver, &releaseEvent);
    }
}
```

---

**Better alternative:** QTest::mouseClick does the same

Comment: You are creating a separate widget in the QGroupBox, but i need to access the builtin CheckBox of the GroupBox which gets visible if the checkable attribute of a QGroupBox is true. See the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgroupbox.html#checkable-prop)

Comment: I do use built-in checkbox which is shown if setCheckable is set to true. No additional widgets are created within QGroupBox. QPushButton is created to trigger a click command and it is located outside QGroupBox

Comment: Ok, but i want to simulate a mouse click on the builtin checkbox of the groupbox directly. Isn't there a way to access the checkbox widget of this groupbox? How would you use QTest::mouseClick for this case (direct attribute access)?

Comment: There is no any QCheckBox instance or other similar instances inside QGroupBox. What you see is just a styled rectangle fully painted and managed by QGroupBox that looks like checkbox. So there are no any "direct" clicks on a checkbox. Every click within QGroupBox's sensitive area is "direct".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So then I will use setChecked as it's doesn't add more complexity to the test.